# Undefined method in professors controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a system that lets users or guests write a review. If users write a review it is associated with their user_id.  If guests write a review they are asked to provide a username which is stored in a column called "guest" in the reviews database.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this but what I've done with the professor_controller is:

```
def show
    @review = Review.where(professor_id: @professor.id).order("created_at DESC")
    @avg_review = @review.average(:hw)
    if @review.user_id = !nil
        @user = User.where(id: @review.user_id) 
    else
        @user = @review.guest
    end
    render
end
```

However, this yields an error:

```
NoMethodError in ProfessorsController#show
undefined method `user_id=' for #<Review::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fed19228e28>
```

I was getting this error even before I put the if statement in. I had the same problem when my controller looked like:

```
def show
    @review = Review.where(professor_id: @professor.id).order("created_at DESC")
    @avg_review = @review.average(:hw)
    @user = User.where(id: @review.user_id) 
end
```

@review works fine so does @avg_review.  The Reviews table has a user_id column and the Users table has an id column.

Comment: `@review.user_id = !nil`  - You don't mean `@review.user_id != nil` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) (a collection of `Review`s), not a single instance of Review. You will need to do `Review.where(professor_id: @professor.id).order("created_at DESC").first` or `Review.find_by_user_id(@professor.id)` to return a single instance.

That said, it sounds like this relationship isn't modeled properly, or there's a better way to express what you want to do through other means. Can you route take in the id of a review as a param?

Comment: Nick I'm not sure what you mean "route take in the id of a review as a param" although by all means I'm open to a more efficient model.

Comment: I'm suggesting a route like `/professors/:id/:review_id` where review is the id of a single review.  That said, I'm confused by the way that you've named `@review` so maybe what you actually want is to have a relationship between users and reviews instead of constructing `user_id` in your controller.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.  However, in this case, you never see the individual review, reviews just display on the professor's page.  So I'm not sure if it would be necessary to have a route like you recommended, correct me if I'm wrong I'm fairly new to rails.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@review` variable actually holds an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, like it clearly says in the error message:

```
NoMethodError in ProfessorsController#show
undefined method `user_id=' for #<Review::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fed19228e28>
```

That's because `where` always returns a Relation, even if it finds only one
record.